# confuse about "miles away from"

Tags: sentence

I would like to use the phrase "miles away from". So I put it in this way.

> He lives in the city which is 30 miles away from Toronto.

I have a question whether I can leave "which is" out of above sentence like this way

> He lives in the city 30 miles away from Toronto.

Comment: Is there only 1 city that is 30 miles away from Toronto?  Maybe you want "***a*** city 30 miles away ..."

Comment: @Jim Yes. And it is normal to elide the word "away", where the place itself is quoted. "The city is 30 miles from Toronto" or (whilst in Toronto) one might say "The city is 30 miles away".

Comment: Don't confuse: "to be miles away from" with "to be [number] miles away from".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example sentences *might* mean the same thing. Commonly, they *would* be taken in the same way.

In the first sentence, there is only one city and it happens to be 30 miles from Toronto. That is the city in which he lives.

(As comments have said, if there is more than a single city 30 miles from Toronto, then the definite article should be replaced by the indefinite article.)

The second sentence is most likely interpreted in just that way too.

---

But there is another possible interpretation of the second sentence—even though it would normally only be understood if a comma were used to stress its meaning:

> He lives in the city, 30 miles away from Toronto.

Rephrasing it further makes this other interpretation even clearer:

> He lives in the *city*—not in the *country*—and is 30 miles away from Toronto.

Here, *city* is being used to describes the *type* of place in which he lives rather than singling out one place in particular.